# О серийном номере и MAC адресе телефона Самсунг Галакси A5 2016

Tags: samsung

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в ситуации.
На коробке  купленного телефона есть наклейка с данными телефона, на этой наклейке написан MAC-адрес, сравнить в телефоне не могу, так как телефон не включается, поломан. Данные должны совпадать в телефоне с наклейкой?
И второй вопрос: MAC-адрес на наклейке коробки может быть серийным номером  телефона или нет?

Answer (score 2):

Между [MAC-адрес](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81) и [серийным номером](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_code) устройства нет никакой связи.

> MAC-адрес - уникальный идентификатор, присваиваемый каждой единице
> активного оборудования или некоторым их интерфейсам в компьютерных
> сетях Ethernet.
>
> **Структура MAC-адреса**
>
> Стандарты IEEE определяют 48-разрядный (6
> октетов) MAC-адрес, который разделён на четыре части.
>
> Первые 3 октета (в порядке их передачи по сети; старшие 3 октета, если
> рассматривать их в традиционной бит-реверсной шестнадцатеричной записи
> MAC-адресов) содержат 24-битный уникальный идентификатор организации
> (OUI), или код MFG (Manufacturing, производителя), который
> производитель получает в IEEE. При этом, в самом первом октете
> используются только 6 старших разрядов, а два младших имеют
> специальное назначение:
>
> Нулевой бит — указывает: для одиночного (0) или группового (1) адресата предназначен кадр;
> Первый бит — указывает, является ли MAC-адрес глобально (0) или локально (1) администрируемым.
>
> Следующие три октета — выбираются изготовителем для каждого экземпляра
> устройства (за исключением сетей системной сетевой архитектуры SNA).
>
> Таким образом, глобально администрируемый MAC-адрес устройства
> глобально уникален и обычно «зашит» в аппаратуру.

[Арифметика расчета серийного номера](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_number_arithmetic) описана стандартом [RFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_Comments) [1982](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1982) и не имеет ничего общего с методикой формирования MAC-адреса.